# rename file when using DD name

Tags: fopen, file-rename, mainframe, zos

In a 'C' language `LP64` compiled program, which will run in Batch, TSO and z/OS UNIX, when opening a PDS(E) member using the following notation (recommended in order to allow file disposition to be used):-

```
hFile = fopen("DD:CONFIG(COPY)", "w");
fclose(hFile);
```

I am surprised to discover that the following does not appear to work:-

```
rename("DD:CONFIG(COPY)","DD:CONFIG(MAIN)");
```

Failing as it does with an `errno` of `ENOENT` (EDC5129I No such file or directory.)

The documentation for [rename](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/rename.htm) says:-

> The rename() function renames memory files and DASD data sets. It also renames individual members of PDSs (and PDSEs)

If instead I do:-

```
rename("//'MYUSER.CONFIG(COPY)'","//'MYUSER.CONFIG(MAIN)'");
```

the `rename()` works.

Alternatively if I do:-

```
rename("//'MYUSER.CONFIG(COPY)'","DD:CONFIG(MAIN)");
```

if fails with an `errno` of `EINVAL` (EDC5121I Invalid argument.)

Why does it not accept the same file name notation that is used for `fopen`?

The reason this is important is because the `rename()` cannot succeed while the PDSE is being browsed by someone. Whereas, using the DD: notation allows an `fopen()` for write to succeed when the PDSE is being browsed because the DISP=SHR coded on the DD name in the JCL is adopted by the `fopen()`.

So, I suppose the real question is - how can my program rename a PDSE member in a way that will succeed when the PDSE is also being browsed by someone?

Comment: This is something I’ve never really thought about. I can speculate but don’t have really good answers. I’m going to guess it depends on how rename is doing things under the covers, whether it’s using SVC 99, doing IDCAMS, or worse (the old days was uncatalog, change VTOC, catalog with new name). I know you can’t rename a member pointing to a DD name in IDCAMS, so I’m guessing there’s a CSI restriction. There’s a little devious part of me that is thinking of invoking TSO to do the rename, but that’s pretty nasty, not knowing the environment where this will be running.

Comment: It could be running in batch or TSO or z/OS UNIX.

Comment: I’ll ponder this tomorrow when I’m back in the home office. This should be solvable, but might require an assembler routine. Oh, a thought - would using something in Zowe be possible?

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr - This is a C language program compiled with LP64. Hopefully that answers your question about Zowe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique required to rename a dataset is different than the technique to rename a member inside a PDS/PDSE...I'd wager that the system rename() function you're calling is just getting this wrong. In z/OS, there are lots of combinations functions like "rename()" have to handle, and it's not unusual to find some that don't work as you expect.

Certainly it's worth a call to IBM Support to see if there's something else going on here...what you're trying to do seems like it should work, so I think there's something to be said for treating it like a bug or documentation error.

Beyond that, as you suggest, you can either use the form of rename that works, or you can replace the system's rename function with something that actually works properly.

One simple way would be to create the rename() as you show it:

```
rename("//'MYUSER.CONFIG(COPY)'","//'MYUSER.CONFIG(MAIN)'");
```

You can get the DSN for a DDNAME using the fldata() function, so it's not hard to create a rename like this on the fly given an open file handle. Beware that the form of rename may allocate the file you specify with DISP=OLD, and hence cause problems if some other task has the file allocated. Also, if this is supposed to be commercial quality code, as a customer, my eyebrows would go up if I found out you needed to launch some external program because you couldn't figure out how to rename a PDS/PDSE member - but that might just be me.

The other alternative is to write your own "rename()" function...unfortunately, it most likely would need to be assembler language if you want it to be efficient. As others suggest, you might spawn off a shell, REXX or TSO command, but of course, that means creating a new process, etc etc etc just to rename the PDS/PDSE member. Keep in mind also that some of these approaches might also have issues with trying to allocate the input file with DISP=OLD.

If that's too slow for your needs, the way to do what you want is to call a small assembler routine that invokes the system STOW service against your DDNAME to do your rename. The flow would be something like this:

1. You'd create a 16-byte area containing the old and new member names. They're 8 characters each and blank padded.
2. You'd need the address of an open DCB that describes the file you're looking at. You can get the DCB address from the FILE structure, I believe - or you could just open a second DCB to the DDNAME you have allocated.
3. You'd call the system STOW service with the parameters that tell it to rename a PDS/PDSE member:

   STOW dcb,area_from_step1,C

In the STOW macro above, the "directory option" of "C" tells STOW that you want to rename an existing member. The area_from_step1 has the current and new member names - the system searches the directory for the current name and rewrites it with the new member name in place.

To be honest, what I describe above is exactly what the system runtime should be doing, but if it's not and IBM doesn't want to fix it, then you might prefer to do this sort of thing "by hand".

Comment: Thanks @Valerie-r, most helpful as always. I have indeed had to use fldata() to work around part of this and get the name myself. But I do agree with you, what is the point of a function such as rename() being provided if it doesn't handle all this for you. I have already raised two RFEs on LE as a result of this project, that have been accepted as uncommitted candidates, so perhaps while I'm on a roll...

Comment: P.S. What did you mean about launching some external program? I don't know what external program you are referring to.

Comment: I'm referring to the ideas of calling IEHPROGM, TSO RENAME and the like as mentioned by some of the other comments...if these programs can do it, then of course your code can as well.

Comment: Ah right - yes. IEHPROGM was a non-starter anyway. Clearly at some level it is possible  since I can be in the same PDSE browsing and on a swap screen I can rename a member, but for some reason, not programatically. How deep does one have to go.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will work, but since you have the dataset already allocated, perhaps you could "call" (for some value of call) IEHPROGM from your program, constucting the proper SYSIN before making the call?

Here's a link to the IBM example for IEHPROGM (mind any break):
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.idau100/u1354.htm

--Scott

Comment: I just read about it, and it states "A RENAME operation will not be processed if the data set or volume is being used by a program executing concurrently. When renaming a member of a partitioned data set, it is your responsibility to ensure that the data set is not currently in use." so I don't think it can solve my problem.